# Setup NIFI to integrate with LDAP on a running cluster

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to configure my secure NIFI cluster to integrate with LDAP.

Which procedure is recommended when doing that on a running cluster?
Do I need to shut down all the nodes?

What steps do I need to take first?

Thanks